# I've been stuck on the bootloader after installing once again (using openSUSE Leap 15.5), but got a different result

Tags: linux, grub2, grub, opensuse

Well, to begin, I'm wanting to run openSUSE Leap 15.5 with the Server role on a HPE Microserver Gen8 using the RAID controller B120i that's embedded, and an Intel Xeon E3-1220Lv2.

When first installing it and rebooting, during the first attempted boot from the hard drive all I was getting was the word GRUB, and nothing more. After researching what GRUB even is, I learned that I'm stuck on the bootloader. After researching some people on a similar problem, I decide to reinstall the OS.

Now I'm getting a different output, and a couple errors, and it boots right into the rescue system. If someone could help me resolve my issue, I'd really appreciate it. It says:

```
Attemting Boot From Hard Drive (C:)
GRUB loading...
Welcome to GRUB!

error: ../../grub-core/fs/btrfs.c:2076:file '/boot/grub2/i386-pc' not found
error: ../../grub-core/fs/btrfs.c:2076:file '/' not found
entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Comment: Start at [Section 6 in the Docs](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:BTRFS#booting) and report back with any issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am almost through the instructions however when i begin to mount /proc it says "mount.bin: /mnt/my-root/proc: mount point does not exist." I have to go to work so I will leave this process on until I get back. Thank you for anymore help you bring.

Comment: Make sure you boot with the Live USB to get that rescue prompt, not your broken grub's rescue prompt.

Comment: I did, I booted it off of the live USB.